# Is installing Web Adaptor mandatory/important with ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, installation

If I am using ArcGIS for Server for my web application is it mandatory or important to install the [ArcGIS Web Adaptor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01540000028p000000)?

I am facing a proxy page configuration issue.

Comment: We have a J2ee app server which is exposed to internet but it is used by specific group of people so more like intranet site.

Comment: My app server and my arcgis server both run in different machine/domains

Answer (score 2):

If you are hosting a web application on a Web server such as IIS, you will need to install the web adaptor.

Will your application be public facing, or is this a sandbox/development environment?

Either way, the Web Adaptor is what allows your web server to communicate with your GIS server and send requests, etc.

Do you have access to the proper documentation to get you through the install?

Here is a [brief overview of the web adaptor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01540000028p000000).

UPDATE BASED ON OP'S COMMENTS:

Anil, you're definitely looking at using the web adaptor. Here's [a little more information.](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2012/05/29/welcome-arcgis-10-1-beta-a-few-tips-for-arcgis-server-migration/)

> There is no longer a differentiation between the Java and .Net versions of ArcGIS for Server.  Now it’s just ArcGIS for Server. The product installs with its own application server; this server should be dedicated to ArcGIS for Server and nothing else. Esri has created applications, called “Web Adapters,” that link your current server of choice (IIS or a J2EE application server) to the GIS server instance. These applications are small broker components that basically forward requests from your web server to the internal server used with ArcGIS. - See more at: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2012/05/29/welcome-arcgis-10-1-beta-a-few-tips-for-arcgis-server-migration/#sthash.XYJ1Jcwy.dpuf

Answer (score 0):

I've recently posted a blog titled [When is the Web Adapter Needed](https://community.esri.com/blogs/eric/2014/06/26/when-is-the-arcgis-web-adapter-needed). You will find a cheat sheet to determined if the web adapter is mandatory for your ArcGIS architecture.